# Simplification of multiple Levi-Civita Epsilons

Tags: tensors

Given the expression:
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\epsilon_{mni}=c\epsilon_{jln}$$
where $c$ is a constant I have to determine. Given the fact:
$$\epsilon_{jln}\epsilon_{jln}=6$$
I have said 
$$c=\frac{\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm}\epsilon_{mni}\epsilon_{jln}}6$$
I am wondering whether it is possible to condense these epsilons further and, if so, how would one do so.(I'm not sure how the sifting property of $\delta$ works for more than $\delta\delta$.
Any pointers or clarifications would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is an expression for the product of two Levi-Civita symbols in terms of the Kronecker delta, namely
$$\varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{imn} = \delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}$$
Applying this to the left-hand side of your equation (and noting that $\varepsilon_{mni} = \varepsilon_{imn}$, you get
$$\begin{align}
\varepsilon_{ijk} \varepsilon_{k \ell m} \varepsilon_{mni}
&= (\delta_{jm} \delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn} \delta_{km}) \varepsilon_{k \ell m} \\
&= \varepsilon_{n \ell j} - \delta_{jn} \varepsilon_{k \ell k}
\end{align}$$

Most of the work is done now, so see if you can take it from here.